# Exibindo determinados vetores em uma lista 2D Python

Tags: python, funções, loop, python-2.7

Tenho a seguinte situação:
- Possuo uma variável chamada (vetor_distancias). Essa variável recebe uma lista 2D com vários vetores.
- Desejo que seja exibido, somente os vetores cuja a soma dos seus índices sejam menores que 100.
- Possuo o código abaixo, porém não está fazendo o que preciso.

---

```
def funcao_fitness():
    fitness = 0
    i = 0
    vetor_distancias = [[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80],[5,6,7,8],[100,200,300,400],[9,15,25,30]]
    for i in vetor_distancias:
        fitness = (fitness + i) if i <= 100
        print (fitness[i])
    return fitness
print (funcao_fitness())
```

---

Desde já, grato pela ajuda.

Comment: A soma dos seus indices ou dos seus valores? ex: [1,2,3] = 6 certo?

Comment: Dos seus valores. Ex. [1,2,3] = 6

Comment: o fitness vai incrementando essa soma caso seja menor que 100 certo?

Comment: Isso. Exatamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
def funcao_fitness():
    fitness = []
    vetor_distancias = [[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80],[5,6,7,8],[100,200,300,400],[9,15,25,30]]
    for subl in vetor_distancias:
        if sum(subl) <= 100:
            fitness.append(subl)
    return fitness
print funcao_fitness()
```

Ou com *list compreension*:

```
def funcao_fitness():
    vetor_distancias = [[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80],[5,6,7,8],[100,200,300,400],[9,15,25,30]]
    return [subl for subl in vetor_distancias if sum(subl) <= 100]
print funcao_fitness()
```

A função vai retornar uma lista com todas as sublistas cuja soma dos seus valores seja <= 100

Comment: É exatamente isso que você fez. Mas preciso que ao invés da soma, seja exibido os vetores. Ex. ao invés de retornar a soma 205, ele me retorne os vetores: [10,20,30,40],[[5,6,7,8] e [9,15,25,30].

Comment: Editado @Danilo, acho que é isso. Ele vai retornar uma lista com todas as sublistas cuja soma dos seus valores seja <= 100

Comment: Perfeito Miguel. Exatamente isso agora.
Mais uma vez, muito, muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: @Danilo de nada quanto à tua pergunta anterior eu cometi um lapso mas já corrigi, vai lá ver para o caso de não teres reparado

Comment: Na outra pergunta que fiz, a sua resposta me atendeu perfeitamente.
Mas vou dar uma olhada na sua edição agora.
Um grande abraço. Você tem me ajudado demais.

Answer (score 1):

Bom como eu estava tentado resolver também para estudo, resolvi postar postar...

```
array = [[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80],[5,6,7,8],[100,200,300,400],[9,15,25,30]]
result = [i for i in array if sum(i) < 100]
print(result)
```

A única diferença da (resposta do @Miguel) será o resultado mesmo..

Onde na solução apresentada o retorno será:

```
[[10, 20, 30, 40], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 15, 25, 30]]
```

E o correto seria:

```
[[5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 15, 25, 30]]
```

Mas pode ser um erro de interpretação...Devido ao operador `<=` onde pelo enunciado o correto é `<`...

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/aoNzmh)

Comment: Olá Magic, isso é porque a tua condição devia ser <= 100 e não só < 100, pelo código da pergunta é <= ,de resto está tudo bem

Comment: Não man, o enunciado é claro : "Desejo que seja exibido, somente os vetores cuja a soma dos seus índices sejam `menores que 100`"... Mas como eu disse pode ser uma diferença nas interpretações...@Miguel

Comment: Tens razão sim, é mesmo diferença nas interpretações. eu segui-me pelo código postado e assumi que seria <= , "`(fitness + i) if i <= 100`" , presumi que fosse mesmo `<=`

Comment: É as vezes o AP pede algo e posta um código inicial que contém erros, mas só ele pode afirmar que ele quer menor ou se quer menor ou igual...@Miguel por isso postei minha resposta, para que caso algum usuário tenha a mesma dúvida ele analise as diferenças,,,

Comment: Está corretissíma também, fizeste bem em postar